# Best way to install Tomcat on Ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, configuration, ubuntu

Is apt-get the generally recommended way to install things on Ubuntu? I tried to install manually, and now having some configuration issues with it.

I'd un-install it and use the apt get command to install it, but do I best install it by deleting the tomcat directories?  There were probably some system variables set in the process.  How do I make sure they don't mess up the future installation?

Also, how does the apt-get command know which version of Tomcat to pull?  And how do I know which version to specify in a way that apt-get can understand? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Probably, but stackoverflow still has a larger and more vibrant community. So I thought I'd post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is off-topic, but [aptitude](http://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude) is the best way to install anything that can be installed via apt-get.

Uninstalling it when you didn't install it through a package manager is [purported](http://www.bodhost.com/web-hosting/uninstalling-tomcat/) to be intractable.